# Default Value in Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I am defining a property in my Azure Model and I want a default value for it. What I am doing is this

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
public Boolean SmsNotification { get; set; }
```

The default value remains to be False. Can anyone tell me how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefaultValue` attribute does not cause the initial value to be initialized with The attribute's value.It doesn't set the actual default value of the attribute in code, it is only for the design.

So :

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool SmsNotification
{
     get { return _smsNotification; }
     set { _smsNotification = value; }
}
```

[For details see this old post.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311339)

Answer (score 2):

The [`DefaultValueAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is just that: an attribute. The documentation is quite clear:

> A visual designer can use the default value to reset the member's value. Code generators can use the default values also to determine whether code should be generated for the member.
>
> **A `DefaultValueAttribute` will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code**.

I don't know if it can word it any clearer that that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a property and set the wrapped field to `true`:

```
public bool mSmsNotification = true;
public bool SmsNotification
{
    get { return mSmsNotification; }
    set { mSmsNotification = value; }
}
```

Comment: Can't I do it with DefaultValue ?

Comment: Looking at Remus' answer, no.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this requires advanced knowledge of `C#`, it's just a property after all, and I think this code is so simple that it explains itself, but I'll do as you suggest.